# How can I track incoming search keywords

Tags: seo, search-engine

Does anyone know how I could track what search terms people are using to arrive at my site. For instance, someone searchs google for 'giant inflatable house' and clicks through to my site. I want to be able to capture those keywords and which search engine they came from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must parse the referer. For exemple a google search query will contains: http://www.google.be/search?q=oostende+taxi&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari

It's a real life query, yes I'm in Oostebde right now :)

See the query string. You can determine pretty easily what I was looking for.

Not all search engines are seo friendly, must major players are.

How to get the referer ? It depends on the script language you use.

Comment: I'm using php so $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] should do the trick right? 
Want to be able to use the keyword data for interacting with my site so google analytics wouldn't really suit. This looks like what I need though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a tool like [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics), [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) is also very useful. It can report a detail analysis of the search queries' impressions, clicks, CTR, position etc.

Comment: This wasn't what I was after but didn't know about webmaster tools so was helpful. thanks